# Vaadin - MenuBar - MenuItem how to get action - maybe javascript

Tags: java, javascript, mouseevent, vaadin

I try to get action at mouseOver and mouseOut for MenuItem in vaadin but without result, maybe someone can help me ?

I want to get behaviour : When I click on menuItem I set the style color for this item, but if I move on other menuItem (without click) I remove the color from last clicked item and set new style for element on which I move the mouse cursor.

I got implementation for set style color but I can't get mouse event at mouseOver/mouseOut - can't add any handler or listener ??

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the client-side `VMenuBar` class and override the following methods:

```
/**
 * When the user hovers the mouse over the item
 *
 * @param item
 */
public void itemOver(CustomMenuItem item) {
   //  ...
}

/**
 * When the mouse is moved away from an item
 *
* @param item
 */
public void itemOut(CustomMenuItem item) {
   //  ...
}
```

Comment: I got class TopMenu which extends MenuBar so I can't extends VMenuBar?